# PHP push associative array in normal array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I have to push an associative array in a normal array (not to convert).
Example (NO CODE):

```
project = {}
element["title"] = "My title"
element["description"] = "My description"
```

is there a way to have this

```
echo $project->title;
//or
echo $project[0]["title"]
```

?
I'v tried this, but server says: ERROR 500

```
    $i = 0;
    $projects = {};
    foreach($projectsElements as $element) {
        while($i <= $nRowsForProject) {
            $idSection = $element->idSection;
            if($idSection == 1) $elements["".$element->internalDescription.""] = $element->text;
            else if($idSection == 2) $elements["".$element->internalDescription.""] = $element->text;
            else if($idSection == 3) $elements["".$element->internalDescription.""] = $element->text;
            $i++;
        }
        array_push($projects,$elements);
        $i=0;
    }
```

Comment: `$projects []= $element;`?

Comment: You confuse things: an object is something different than an array. The `->` operator references a property inside an object, but that is not possible in a declarative manner. Also creating an object is not possible by a simple `$projects = {};` as you attempt to, that is a syntax error (your error 500). Instead you typically have to implement a class of which you then can instantiate an object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$projects = {};` is not valid php.

If you want to initialize an empty array (associative or numeric, that does not matter), you need:

```
$projects = [];
```

or on older php versions:

```
$projects = array();
```

Also note that you need to do the same to your `$elements` array at the beginning of each iteration otherwise it will grow on every iteration. Assuming that the descriptions are not all the same...

```
foreach($projectsElements as $element) {
    $elements = [];
    while($i <= $nRowsForProject) {
        ...
```

And your `while` loop does not seem to make a lot of sense: You are not using the `$i` variable in your loop so are just doing the same assignments on each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

```
$projects = []; // declare empty array
foreach($projectsElements as $element) {
  $projects []= $element; // push $element into $projects array
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$i = 0;
$projects = array();
foreach($projectsElements as $element) {
    while($i <= $nRowsForProject) {
    $elements = array();
        $idSection = $element->idSection;
        if($idSection == 1) $elements["".$element->internalDescription.""] = $element->text;
        else if($idSection == 2) $elements["".$element->internalDescription.""] = $element->text;
        else if($idSection == 3) $elements["".$element->internalDescription.""] = $element->text;
        $i++;
    }
    array_push($projects,$elements);
    $i=0;
}
```